# Remove special characters from a dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, nlp, text-processing

I have a data frame that has a column with text data in it. I want to remove special characters from the text data. 
For eg, the df column looks similar to this-

```
user_id     text data column
    1        Have a nice day ahead!! take care...@Kol...
    2        #hello....world!!
    3        Good_Bye's
    4        https://www.facebook.com
    5        "Merry Christmas"
```

The output should be:

```
user_id     text data column
    1        Have a nice day ahead take care Kol
    2        hello world
    3        Good Byes
    4        https www facebook com
    5        Merry Christmas
```

How to do this using python

Comment: You can use regex `(?=\S)(\W+)` and `.replace()` to do that.